# How to copy and truncate/pad an array

Tags: c++, std

I have a header from a packet that contains various pieces of information about the sender; I'd like to parse it in C++.
The array comes in the form of a byte array (`unsigned char[24]`)

In Java, I'd probably parse it using something like `Array.copyOfRange()` to grab the first 4 bytes, the next 4 bytes, etc. etc.

But in C++, there's not an obvious way to accomplished this.  I've looked at vector, array, and copy from the standard library, but none of them seem to be able to slice the array (and truncate or pad it) in the way that I'd like.

Is there something in the standard library that would do this, or do I need to roll out my own solution?

Comment: Given that the standard library components all do that, e.g., `std::vector<T>` can slice and dice the sequence, potentially in combination with suitable algorithms, I think you'd need to be more specific about what you want/need!

Comment: From what you said, `memcpy` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

most containers will take a pointer range eg string(A+0,A+4). Which with pointer arithmetic solves this:

```
unsigned char A[24];

vector<unsigned char> v0(A+0,A+4); // per chunk

for(int i=0; i<24; i+=4) { // or in a loop
    vector<unsigned char> chunk(A+i,A+i+4);
    ...
}
```